# How to deliver structured text data to a pebble watch app?

Tags: c, pebble-sdk

As a relative noob to C, I'm looking for a better way to deliver structured textual data to my watch app in a way that allows the watch app to decode it in a nested loop.

The data consists of a variable number of records containing two values like:
(record1) value 1, value 2, (record2) value 3, value 4, etc...

Currently I'm sending the data as a string with PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble, as a double-delimited string, using ":" between records and "|" between values, like "value1 | value2 : value3| value4..." and using [mstrtok](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320.1.3/string/FreeBSD/strtok.c) to decompress the data when it arrives.

This is working (sort of) but a) is very expensive on memory b)is, I suspect, leading to some crashes and c) uses some fancy C code that I just don't understand.

I'm using the data to construct a simpleMenuItem on the watch.

Since I'm generating the data in java from my Android companion app, I am able to structure the data in any way I like.
So, the question is:

Is it possible to construct a byte-array from this data, like JSON or something,  that could be mapped into a structure that I'd be able to iterate through to extract the two values into local *char variables?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. This depends highly on one's knowledge of how strings, ints, etc work in C. Are you planning on *only* sending `int`s? If so, then the answer is very simple.

Comment: I'm planning on sending only character strings, and I have a basic understanding of how null-terminated character sequences can be interpreted as strings..I'd love to hear the simple solution ...please?